# Dynamically create method and store in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I've never done anything like this before, and am wondering what my options may be.

An application I'm working on queries a third party monitoring system for SNMP Attributes.  Some attributes return a value such as 1/100 seconds since Epoch time.  Others return number of seconds, which can be converted to a TimeSpan, etc.  What I want to enable, via a Web UI, is for a person to pick the SNMP attribute, and be able to create their own Conversion method, which can then be stored in a database, and be used every time someone wanted to see the "converted" (and more meaningful) value.

It would be best for it to be as dynamic as something like Excel, where you can simply enter your formula, and be able to come up with a result.  What are my options to do something like this inside of ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is having JavaScript functions, that would run in the browser. You could also run the JavaScript on the server, using e.g. [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)

Then there are many options from using C# as the language (and Reflection.Emit for code generation) to creating your own simple DSL along with an interpreter.

Yet another solution might be to let users specify the conversion function in SQL, so the converted value can be stored alongside the original one.

For all of these options, carefully evaluate security implications (executing user code on other users machines and / or your server).